# java dom escape characters

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have a trouble with escaping characters while I create XML file with DOM. In result file I need to escape characters: `&`, `<`, `>`, `"`, `'`. After generating XML file DOM automatically escapes characters `&`, `<`, `>`. But characters `"` and `'` are not escaped. If I change these characters manually to `&quot;` and `&apos;` before generating XML, DOM escapes the symbols `&`. And the result is like this: `&amp;apos;`.

How can I fix it? Maybe I can setup to DOM to escape the symbols `"` and `'` or maybe it is possible to escape all characters manually and disable automatic escape by DOM.

Comment: What is the actual issue? This is the perfect, expected behaviour.

Comment: actual issue is to create finished XML with escaped symbols & < > " '

Comment: at this time DOM escapes only & < >

Comment: what library are you using to generate the XML?

Comment: I use org.w3c.dom and javax.xml.transform

Comment: At this time as a workaround I reopen after generation the XML file and scan all XML nodes and change the symbols. But I think it is not right way

Comment: The "right way" is not to care - the DOM ouput algorithm you're using will escape the characters that need to be escaped and not the ones that don't.  The only time it _needs_ to replace `"` with `&quot;` is when it is outputting a double quote within a double quoted attribute value (and likewise `'` within a single quoted attribute value).  At all other times it's fine to leave the character unescaped without changing the meaning of the XML.  There is nothing that needs to be "fixed".

Comment: The generated xml should be sent to the bank to process. It is the bank requirements to change these symbols. So I need to change these in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with workaround.
I reopen the file after creation and change the symbols all that I need.
Maybe it is not so good solution, but it works fine.